# multiprocessing in winforms application

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, winforms, multiprocessing

I'm working on about 35 batches updating many databases as a part of our daily process at work. Every batch of them was developed in a single web app. Due to database issues, i have collected all of them in one windows application to make use of DB connection pooling and i have assigned a single backgroundworker for each batch. Reaching to 20 batch in the application, every thing is working good. But when i add any other backgroundworker for any other batch, the application hangs.I think this is because i'm running too many threads in one process. Is there a solution for this problem, for example, making the application working with many processes ??!!!.
Regards,

Note,
I have assigned a single machine for this application (Core i7 cpu, 8 gb ram).

Comment: The number of threads should be irrelevant as cause for your problem. Please be more specific of where your code hangs. Use a debugger to see in what state the threads of your program are when it hangs. If you believe you know which is the hanging/offending code, post it here so that we can help.

Comment: Dear elgonzo, the problem is that the UI is hanging and i can't minimize or maximize the window, i can't press any button. I just need a way that i can make the UI perform faster with all of those backgroundworkers. Thanks for ur reply .

Comment: Use a debugger. Right now you ask us to poke in the dark and make a blind guess. Maybe you have a deadlock, maybe you have too many DB connections open, maybe something different. Who knows...?

Comment: Ahh... do you actually mean that your program freezes from time to time and recovers if the pending batches are completely processed? Or do you mean "hanging" as in "crashed"/"dead"?

Comment: till now, i have tested too many options. the only case in which the application hangs is that i run too many backgroundwotkers. starting with one or two or even 10, every thing is ok. when i run more that 15 or 20, the dtatabase updates run normally but the UI hangs (i mean that batches are running in the background but the UI is hanging). what can i do for the UI to work normally ??!! .

Comment: yes, the application is running but it freezes all the time. not also that batches are running all the time. i mean that the batch run again when it end, it may run 10 times per second. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

How many databases you have to update?

I think it is more recommended to have the number of Threads as the number of Databases

Comment: good solution, but every batch have a specific job and a different time of running. ie, one run every 30 seconds, the other run every 5 seconds and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If your UI is freezing while many background workers are active, but recovers when those background workers are finished processing, then likely the UI thread is executing a method which waits for a result or signal from one of the  background worker threads.

To fix your problem, you will have to look for UI-related code that deals with synchronization / multi-threading. This might be places where one of the many synchronization objects of .NET are being used (including the `lock` statement), but it could also involve "dumb" polling loops a-ka `while(!worker.IsFinished) Thread.Sleep();`.

Another possible reason for the freeze might be that you are running a worker (or worker-related method) accidentally in the UI thread instead in a background thread.

But you will find out when you use the debugger.

To keep the scope of your hunt for problematic methods managable, let your program run in the debugger until the UI freezes. At that moment, pause the program execution in the debugger. Look which code the UI thread is processing then, and you will have found one instance of offending code. (Whatever there is wrong, i can't tell you - because i don't know your code.)

It is quite possible that different UI-related methods in your code will suffer from the same issue. So, if you found the offending code (and were able to fix it) you would want to check on for other problematic methods, but that should be rather easy since at that point of time you will know what to look for...